# junit testing for asynchronous callback method

Tags: android, asynchronous, junit, callback

I want to do Unit Tests for asynchronous methods in android.
I have an asynchronous callback method inside a `MainActivity`. Code is shared below.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IcallBacks{
Object object;
ResultClass resultClass;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button=findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    resultClass = new ResultClass(this,10);
}

@Override
public void callBack(Object object) {
    this.object=object;
    Log.d("CallBack", "callBack: ");
 }
}
```

**Result.java** is the class which give `asynchronous callback`. That code is shared below.

**Result.java**

```
public class ResultClass {
IcallBacks icallBacks;
public ResultClass(final IcallBacks icallBacks, int a) {
    this.icallBacks=icallBacks;
    Log.d("CallBack", "ResultClass: Constructor");
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                icallBacks.callBack(this);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
  }
}
```

Interface class is also shared below

**IcallBacks.java**

```
public interface IcallBacks {
    public void callBack(Object object);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your MainActivity dependence of your ResultClass, so if you want to test the logic of MainActivity, you should decouple them, you need to inject your ResultClass not create direct in onCreate method, you can use Dagger library to help you, or pass the RunClass instance by Intent, the sample use latter one.

After you do the injection to decouple them, i suggest add a method to your RunClass to start the async work, e.g start(IcallBacks callback), this is for mock the method callback logic:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implement IcallBacks {
    @Override
    protected onCreate(Bundle) {
        // again, use Dagger is better
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        RunClass async = b.getSerialible("callback");
         .... other code
        async.start(this);
    }
}

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class UnitTest {
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class, true, false);
    private RunClass mAsync;
    private Bundle startupData;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        mAsync = Mockito.mock(RunClass.class);
        startupData = new Bundle();
        // suppose RunClass implement Serializable, you should use Dagger for better
        startupData.putSerializable("callback", mAsync); 
    }

    @Test
    public void callbackTest(){
        when(mAsync.start(any(IcallBacks.class).thenAnswer(i -> {
            IcallBacks callback = i.getArgument(0);
            callback.callBack(mAsync);
            return null;
        });
        // start your activity
        mActivityRule.launchActivity(new Intent().putExtras(startupData));
    }
```

Comment: I have to test locally not for instrumentation test